# Must the QQ-plot line be at a 45 degree angle?

Tags: r, regression, normal-distribution, qq-plot

A qq-plot for a regression I ran looks like this:

[image]

My understanding was always that there should be a 45 degree angle, i.e. from approx bottom left to top right corner. Must that really be the case? Or is the following QQ-plot fine and normality can +- be assumed (apart from the heavy tails).

Feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This can be a helpful plot but if allowed only one plot I would choose residuals vs fitted.

Comment: The reference line *is* at a 45 degree angle.  You cannot tell that because of the large relative distortion in scales between the horizontal and vertical axes.

Answer (score 1):

If the residuals are Normal, the points on the QQ plot should *closely* follow the line. For the most part ($|r_i| < 2$) the point are close to the dotted line.

As you said, the tails are heavy. These tails are **very heavy**. If we had a one or two residuals that were a little bit to big (say not much more than $\pm 3$) I would usually say that its 'Normal enough'. Here you have quite a lot of $|r_i| > 3$ and one that looks to be as big as $9$? The probability of observing a standardised residual larger as $9$ under a standard normal is $\approx 10^{-19}$. This suggests that there is a **very serious** discrepancy between your model and the data. There are also lots of other large outliers in your data so I would be very worried about how well it generalises to the real world.

Comment: What John Tukey called Winsor's principle was that all distributions are normal in the middle. That was exaggeration for effect, but this is a good example.